# Msbuild still referencing old files in Include=*.cs after deleting files

Tags: msbuild

I have theproblem that an ItemGroup is not updating and therefore trying to copy files that do not exist anymore, which throws an error:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Others Include=".\Folder\**\*" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Now when I delete a file in `Folder`, it still tries to copy it and Visual Studio still shows it in the file list.
It would make sense that Visual Studio forces a reload of the project if some files change, or better yet: update silently.

Answer (score 0):

If I get it correctly:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Others Include=".\Folder\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
<RemoveFile ... >
<CopyFile...> <!-- throws an error -->
```

Solution:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <Others Include=".\Folder\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
<RemoveFile ... >
<ItemGroup> <!-- refresh Others collection -->
    <Others Include=".\Folder\**\*" />
</ItemGroup>
<CopyFile...> <!-- should be ok now -->
```

Comment: I described my problem poorly: The deleting and copying around of files happens outside of msbuild. The user copies files or deletes files and my msbuild script is supposed to keep an updated list in the ItemGroup.

Comment: Try to exclude all files from Folder in VS. If you want to see theese files in the VS, click on the Show all files in solution explorer. This way you will have updated list of files in the Folder and your script should not be broken (if you update Others collection before any Folder file operation)

Comment: Ludwo, your refreshment should actually create duplicate entries in the ItemGroup

Answer (score 0):

It's how msbuild works. It won't re-evaluate the ItemGroup without reason and all globally-scoped evaluations will happen before any targets run. Target-scoped items willbe evaluated when target got executed.

You can use simple condition check before copying - like **Condition='Exists(...)'** on your itemgroup elements. Or if it's in your control - recreate itemgroup with another name and include only items that currently exits. Both ways are simple and valid scenarios.
If you'll add more details about your script or what are you trying to achieve - it would help us to help you with more specific answer.